# How can I connect the output of the SDF.NDTable with the Compressor efficiency?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, dymola

I have created a 4D matrix with dummy data for an efficiency. I can successfully retrieve and interpolate this data with the SDF.NDTable.
Now the output efficiency of the SDF.NDTable should be linked into an EFFCompressor.

When i connect the output to the one of the efficiency i get a error in Dymola.

[image: model]
[image: input compressor]
[image: Error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with SDF. Instead, you are struggling with a fundamental Modelica concept: *variability*. Variables can be declared with 4 different kinds of *variability*, defined in the following increasing order:

1. **constant**: Fixed in the model, not changeable by the user
2. **parameter**: Fixed for the simulation, changeable by the user before translation or simulation start
3. **discrete**: Can change during the simulation at events
4. **continuous**: Can change continuously during the simulation

A parameter can be computed from a constant, but constants not from parameters. Similar, continuous variables have the highest variability, so they can be computed from constants, parameters, discrete variables and continuous variables, but none of the others can be computed from a continuous variable.

I recommend to read some Modelica literature to learn such things.
A good resource is [https://mbe.modelica.university/](https://mbe.modelica.university). The concept of variability is explained [here](https://mbe.modelica.university/behavior/equations/variables/).

Comment: In addition to this: models may be significantly simpler if a variable is a parameter than if it were a continuous-time variable. A classic example is capacitance - where you have to replace C*der(i)=v by another equation if C is time-varying (but for resistance it just works). I don't know what changes, if any, would be needed if volumetricEfficiency would be time-varying.

Comment: What would need to be done is to change the compressor model for "volumetricEfficiency" to be an input instead of a parameter. Although that could come with some more necessary changes...